# In KendoUI Grid - make grid using C# viewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My scenario is , I've controller which is passing ViewModel Object to view .

For one model we can return json array from controller . but what for multiple objects case like ViewModel  And the thing is that for each list (In my viewmodel object) i need to make a seperate Grid . Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Can you just clarify something for me. Do you want to produce 1 grid that is bound to a List that is contained within your viewmodel or do you want several grids bound to several different lists within your viewmodel? Also are you using pure js/html version or the MVC wrappers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it like this before - in your javascript, you can generate a kendo datasource from the object in your viewmodel:

```
var yourDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeObject)) });
yourDataSource.read();
```

More often than not though, I wire the up to a service so the loading of the data can by asynchronous, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer of my own question . we can make grid using viewmodel object which further includes multiple objects simply by doing the following code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.accountHistory).Name("Account_History").Columns())
```